# How to display a dialog if spinner is not selected or skipped

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am developing an app in android and in that i want to validate Spinner i.e if a Spinner is not selected or skipped then i want to display an alert dialog displaying a message that "Please select the particular spinner and move forward". In the sense i want to make the user to compulsory select the spinner without skipping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the first item in your `spinner` something like this: PLease select so and so..

Say `Spinner s;`

Then check using `String st =s.getSelectedItem().toString()` or

`int pos =s.getSelectedItemPosition()`

Then you should either use:

```
if(pos!=0)
                {
                \\do your work
                }
                else{
                \\display alert
       }
```

OR

```
 if(!st.equals("Please select so and so.."))
     {
                    \\do your work
                    }
                    else{
                    \\display alert
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

For spinner, you can use `onItemSelected()` to check for null values. If it is null, then display the dialog. For dialog, you can refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: onItemSelected() method is called only when the spinner is selected,here i am not selecting any item from Spinner,just when the focus comes on spinner i am just shifting to another focus e.g editfield and if done so i want to display the dialog box.

Comment: By default, Spinner would be displaying it's first item. you can set condition if onItemSelected is at the first position or null. depending on how you set in your xml file. if you need more help, you need to include you codes in your question.